# Why is the calculation of the semimajor axis of an orbit negative?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, orbital-motion

Say an object with an initial kinetic energy $\frac12 mv^2$ is launched from the surface of the Earth into an elliptical orbit with area $\pi ab$ without loss of energy. ($a$ is semimajor axis, $b$ is semiminor)

What are the apsides of this orbit?

---

I know that when an object is at this red point here

[image]

the distance between it and both foci are exactly $a$.

Hence, WLOG I let the object be at this point in orbit. The velocity of the object at this point is given by the vis viva equation where we have $$v = \sqrt{GM\over a}$$

The energy of the object at this point is $$\text{KE}+\text{GPE} = \frac12 m \sqrt{GM\over a}^2 - \frac{GMm}a = -\frac{GMm}{2a}$$

I plan to find the semimajor axis, which will enable me to calculate the semiminor axis and the eccentricity, and finally the apsides.

Equating the energy of the object at the red point and its initial energy gives
$$\frac12 v^2 = -\frac{GM}{2a} \iff a = -\frac{GM}{v^2}$$

However, this expression is clearly negative?

What did I do wrong?

Comment: ${1 \over 2} m v^2$ isn't the initial total energy.  It is the initial kinetic energy.

Comment: @Malcolm see edit

Comment: Why do you believe that the total energy at point b is just the kinetic energy ${1 \over 2} m v^2$?

Comment: @Malcolm what is the point b that you refer to? if you mean at the start, isn't the gravitational potential energy 0 (since surface of earth) so there is only kinetic energy?

Comment: The gravitational energy is NOT 0 at the surface.  By point b I meant your red spot.  At that point the potential energy is $-{G M m \over 2 b}$.

Comment: The ${1 \over r}$ gravitational potential goes to zero at an infinite separation.

Comment: @Malcolm Ah i see, I added a -GMm/R_earth for the launch energy and it worked. thanks

Comment: @Malcolm There is no "point b". $b$ is the length of the semi minor axis. The label $b$ just happens to be near the red dot, so it easy to think it does represent some point $b$.